# on click hide list style

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello to all i want to hide list style when i click anywhere on body. In code by default it hide ,when i clicked on button it shows a list. But it can't hide when i click on anywhere. Can anyone please tell me how do i this ??

```
.dss {
        background: #FFF;
        color: #0086EE;
        display: none;
        padding: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        z-index: 10;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.45) 0 0 9px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.45) 0 0 9px;
        box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.45) 0 0 9px;
    }
```

Also see the js code:-

```
function show() {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
    }


Also see the html:-

<input type="submit" value="select services" onclick="show()" style="border: none; background: transparent; width: 95px;" />
        <!--<select onFocus="show()" style="background: #FFF;border: none; display:none;cursor: pointer;height: 33px;left: 0;opacity: 0;position: absolute;top: 10px;width: 8%;">
    <option>a</option>
  </select>-->
        <div class="dss" id="demo">
            <ul style="list-style: none;">
                <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is your dropdown

Comment: it's list-style not dropdown.

Comment: Then You should have given list-style instead dropdown. Add a fiddle jsfiddle.net to explain your problem. Check my answer

Comment: try this $('body').click(function(e) { // hide dropdownlist })

Comment: check this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp , in your code you have only a list , you need to include a drop down for your purpose just go through the link it will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
function show()
{
 document.getElementById("demo").style.display="block";
}

$(function(){
    $('#demo').click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation(); });
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(event){  show(); event.stopPropagation(); });
    $('html').click(function(){
       $('#demo').hide();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed from you question, you want to hide dropdown while clicking a button.

```
 document.getElementById("ButtonID").onclick=function()
 {
   document.getElementById("DropdownID").style.display='none'; // Thanks for the correction
 }
```

If you have further problems, please add your select dropdown

If you want to hide it by clicking anywhere in the body, replace that buttonID click.

So the problem of your javascript functions. You should have written body click first and then that button click which displays ul.

```
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onclick = function(){//Hide UL}

  document.getElementById("ButtonID").onclick = fucntion(//show UL){}
```

Comment: style.display=none; should be like style.display= 'none'; correct it